# how to flatten multiple child nodes using jsonNodeReference in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

i have a json file with the below format.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "product": {
        "code": "104AB001",
        "names": [
          {
            "lang_code": "fr_CM",
            "name": "BANOLE"
          },
          {
            "lang_code": "f_CM",
            "name": "BANOLE"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "product": {
        "code": "104AB002",
        "names": [
          {
            "lang_code": "fr_CM",
            "name": "BANOLE"
          },
          {
            "lang_code": "f_CM",
            "name": "BANOLE"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using a copy activity and

```
"jsonNodeReference": "$.['results'][*].['product'].['names']",
                "jsonPathDefinition": {
                    "product__code": "$.['results'][*].['product'].['code']",
                    "product__names__lang_code": "['lang_code']",
                    "product__names__name": "['name']"
                }
```

The expected output is

```
product__code   product__names__lang_code   product__names__name
104AB001        fr_CM                       BANOLE
104AB001        f_CM                        BANOLE
104AB002        fr_CM                       BANOLE
104AB002        f_CM                        BANOLE
```

But i am getting
[Azure data factory output as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3aRY.png.)
When i did search in stack overflow and google, i got some info like it is not possible in azure data factory. below are the links

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ebcef1f-5817-434c-9426-a83e9df35965/jsonnodereference-and-jsonpathdefinition-for-multiple-child-nodes?forum=AzureDataFactory

https://medium.com/@gary.strange/flattening-json-in-azure-data-factory-2f2130794258

My question is here, if it is not possible in azure data factory then what could be the other solution to achieve this.

Comment: Have you checked the URL[link] (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/v1/data-factory-supported-file-and-compression-formats.md) . Also looks like you may not need [*] after results in jsonPathDefinition

Comment: @Alok: i tried by removing the * after results in jsonPathDefinition and it doesnt bring any data for product__code.

Answer (score 0):

Only one array can be flattened in a schema. Multiple arrays can be referenced—returned as one row containing all of the elements in the array. However, only one array can have each of its elements returned as individual rows. This is the current limitation with jsonPath.

However you can first convert json file with nested objects into CSV file using Logic App and then you can use the CSV file as input for Azure Data factory. Please refer below URL to understand how Logic App can be used to convert nested objects in json file to CSV.

[link] "https://adatis.co.uk/converting-json-with-nested-arrays-into-csv-in-azure-logic-apps-by-using-array-variable/"

Thanks